# How to find out members of a group and group of a member from a table of group changes

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in python about several individuals (Person 1,2,3,4,5) and several groups (groups A,B,C). I have a table (currently as a pandas dataframe) of the initial state (`time == 0`) of the individuals and groups:

```
Person | Group
-------|-------
 1     |   A
 2     |   A
 3     |   C
 4     |   B
 5     |   B
```

And a table (also a pandas DF) of people changing groups. The table includes the person, their new group, and the time of the change.

```
Person | New Group | Time
-------|-----------|------
  1    |  B        |  10
  1    |  A        |  12
  3    |  A        |  13
  4    |  C        |  13
  1    |  C        |  22
  5    |  A        |  30
```

I need to write a function that can return a list of the people in a group at a given time

```
people = people_in_group(group, time)  # type(people) == list
```

and a function that can return the group a person is in at a given time

```
group = group_member(person, time)
```

What is the most appropriate data structure to build from these two tables that would make it easiest to query in both directions like this?

Answer (score 0):

You current df has unique times so each list of people in a group would have one person

Given a dataframe like this with duplicate time values:

```
    Person  New Time
1   1       B   10
2   1       A   12
3   3       A   12
4   4       C   13
5   1       C   22
6   5       A   30

df.groupby(['New', 'Time']).Person.apply(list)
```

Gives

```
 New        Time
 A    12    [1, 3]
      30    [5]
 B    10    [1]
 C    13    [4]
      22    [1]
```

Comment: I think unique times is not a safe assumption. I added a simultaneous group change to illustrate that. However, a person will not switch to two groups simultaneously, so a person will only ever be in a single group at one time. Does that materially change your proposed solution?

Comment: Its not an assumption. This code will work even if the time is not unique